# main method failed to execute glitch?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point, execute

Was just testing a simple code, and it appears my eclipse just got worse. This code is suppose to output 2. But when I run it, very weird error says 'Error: Main method not found in class jasc1, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)' when my main method is clearly defined.

Does anyone know what this error is all about??

```
public class jasc1 {

     int a = 2;

     public void abc(){
         System.out.print(a);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
         new jasc1().abc();
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the file name?

Comment: it is under /jasc project name. im not sure how to check the file name

Comment: Working fine on my end. I added your code to a .java file with the same name as the class (a requirement), and it outputs '2' as you would expect.

Comment: Alternatively, do you have a second class of the same name without a main? That could cause your issue.

Comment: no I created a fresh project with all the classes having a main, right click run as java app..

Comment: All the classes have a main? Only one class per project should have a main method. Otherwise how does the system know which class to start when the project runs?

Comment: @RudiKershaw if you have more than one class with `public static void main(String args[])` you can run what class you want in Eclipse and NetBeans IDEs by right-clicking the class and selecting Run...

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me, your file name must be wrong.  It MUST be the same as the class name.

**Additionally**

Class names should (by convention) begin with an upper case letter so `Jasc1`

Comment: @Starting with capital in not required, it's a convention only

Comment: added a note to that effect

Comment: thanks i'll keep that in mind.. and I changed my project name from jasc to jasc1, and it ran fine. :) .. but when I made another class jasc2, error popped up again :(

Comment: if you make a class `jasc2` then should be in it's own file called `jasc2.java`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a class It should have a method `public static void main(String [] args)` (or similar meanings). But, for executing a class you have to run that class.

**ex:** In command line you call `java jasc1` after compiling it with `javac jasc1.java` (ofcourse there are some options like `-cs`; see help)

The same way you can run one class in Eclipse or NetBeans IDEs by right-clicking on it in the project explorer and select Run or Run as

Of course, this `jasc1` class cannot call another class that have a `public static void main(String []args)` method.